# angular typescript enum to array is null in module forRoot configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I am facing weird problem with Angular 6 and TypeScript. The problem is that enum is being converted into array and passed to module using forRoot method of that module. While console.logging anywhere else - passed array exists, but if console.logged inside of the service provider - array is `null`. I am attaching the repo, which would help to reproduce the issue. The issue appears only with built files or while serving with `ng serve --prod`.

[This is the repository of the reproducible issue](https://github.com/trimpirim/angular6-typescript-enum-for-root-failing)

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] on stackblitz instead ?

Comment: You won't be able to run `ng serve --prod` or `ng build --prod` using the stackblitz.

Comment: But here you go - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2a5zne

Comment: I won't need to, it's ran automatically. If you can't reproduce your issue on stackblitz, then it's a typo error. And I frankly don't want to proof read all of your files to find a single typo ...

Comment: My repo and stackblitz have only one difference - different packages. Nothing else, yet, the problem exists if I run `ng serve --prod` or `ng build --prod`. Where do they document that stackblitz run `ng serve --prod` or `ng build --prod`?

Comment: if the prod flag is in issue, this could be because of minification or AOT. Since you didn't get an aswer other than mine in an hour, you should consider opening an issue on  Angular's repository (with screenshots and your own repo, since you can't reproduce it on stackblitz), and ask directly to their team what goes wrong.